# Catch inside while loop

Tags: java, exception, stack-overflow

I am converting string to Integer, so when I receive any character, exception is thrown and execution is getting stopped. I want to skip that character and print all the remaining numbers so I kept catch inside the while loop. But now for each and every exception one error will be thrown and the remaining numbers are getting printed as per exception, but code has to send mail to the team once an exception is thrown (I will place the mailing part inside catch). It will not be good if code sends mail when each and every time exception is thrown so I have to collect all the exceptions inside that while loop and send mail at once regarding all the exception. Is it possible?

I will place the simple sample code. (Mailing part I will handle later as of please tell me the logic to collect all the exception and printing at once.)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class dummy {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String getEach="";
        List A  = new ArrayList();
        A.add("1");
        A.add("2");
        A.add("3");
        A.add("AA");
        A.add("4");
        A.add("5");
        A.add("dsfgfdsgfdshg");
        A.add("30");
        Iterator<String> map = A.iterator();

        while (map.hasNext()) {
            try {
                getEach = map.next();
                int getValue = Integer.parseInt(getEach);
                System.out.println("Value:::::: "+getValue);
            } catch (Exception E) {
                System.out.println("There is an exception c" +E.getMessage()); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `List`, add every exception (or the massages) to it, and send one mail after the loop, that contains all the messages...

Comment: Could you format your source code first? It is a little hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a List class with an Exception object then collect it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class dummy {

    public static void main(String args[])

    {
        String getEach = "";

        List<String> A = new ArrayList<String>();
        A.add("1");
        A.add("2");
        A.add("3");
        A.add("AA");
        A.add("4");
        A.add("5");
        A.add("dsfgfdsgfdshg");
        A.add("30");
        Iterator<String> map = A.iterator();
        List<Exception> errList = new ArrayList<Exception>();
        while (map.hasNext()) {
            try {
                getEach = map.next();
                int getValue = Integer.parseInt(getEach);
                System.out.println("Value:::::: " + getValue);
            } catch (Exception E)
            {

                //System.out.println("There is an exception c" + E.getMessage());
                errList.add(E);
            }
        }

        if(!errList.isEmpty())
        {
            for(Iterator<Exception> eIter = errList.iterator();eIter.hasNext();)
            {
                Exception e = eIter.next();

                System.out.println("There is an exception c" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could I suppose just drop the **try/catch** altogether and use something like this:

```
while(map.hasNext()) {
    getEach = map.next();
    // If getEach contains the string representation of 
    // a Numerical value. The regular expression within
    // the matcher below will handle signed, unsigned, 
    // integer, and double numerical values. If getEach
    // holds a numerical value then print it.
    if (getEach.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
        int getValue = Integer.parseInt(getEach);
        System.out.println("Value:::::: "+getValue);
    }
}
```